# how to make custom field name in spring data mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Please look below for a better understanding of the problem statement!

```
@Document
class A{
@ID
private int id;

@Field(value="v1")
private String value;

.
.
}
```

When we persist `object A` in mongodb, `key v1` will be stored for private property value. Let me take a simple example.

Suppose we create `object A` in this way-

```
class a = new class();
a.setId(1);
a.setValue("hello");

a = new class();
a.setId(2);
a.setValue("how r u?");
```

If we save above created objects in mongodb, data will be stored in db would be like

`{"_id":1,"v1":"hello"} {"_id":2,"v1":"how r u?"}`

but I need to get key `v2`(or may be some other) in
place of `v1` second time. Actually as per my work requirement, I need to store a different key for value property and key name I will get at the time of `class a` creation.

Any idea? How I can do it?

Regards

Comment: you can create a mapppingConverter http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add your other fields to the bean with `@Document` annotation. And when you get the result of your query, you can then transfer the values you want to a new bean (Data Transfer Object - DTO).